# Copy constructor: deep copying an abstract class

Tags: c++, constructor, abstract-class, deep-copy

Suppose I have the following (simplified case):

```
class Color;

class IColor
{
public: 
    virtual Color getValue(const float u, const float v) const = 0;
};

class Color : public IColor
{
public:
    float r,g,b;
    Color(float ar, float ag, float ab) : r(ar), g(ag), b(ab) {}
    Color getValue(const float u, const float v) const 
    { 
        return Color(r, g, b)
    }
}

class Material
{
private:
    IColor* _color;
public:
    Material();
    Material(const Material& m);
}
```

Now, is there any way for me to do a deep copy of the abstract IColor in the copy constructor of Material? That is, I want the values of whatever m._color might be (a Color, a Texture) to be copied, not just the pointer to the IColor.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Take a look at [the virtual constructor idiom](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Virtual_Constructor)

Answer (score 8):

You could add a clone() function to your interface.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to add that code yourself to the Material copy constructor. Then code to free the allocated IColor in your destructor.

You'll also want to add a virtual destructor to IColor.

The only way to do a deep copy automatically would be to store a color directly instead of a pointer to an IColor.

Comment: Because by default it will simply copy the pointer address into the copied pointer address.   It will not copy what is being pointed to and then re-adjust the pointer.  Luke has the best suggestion in making a clone() function called from the copy constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a clone() method to color is probably best, but if you don't have that option, another solution would be to use dynamic_cast to cast IColor* to Color*.  Then you can invoke the Color copy constructor.

Comment: But you don't know if it is a Color or a Texture, how can you dynamic_cast then ?

Comment: If the object is not of type color then dynamic_cast<Color *>(_color) will return null.  (Dynamic cast / rtti can detect what the actual type is as long as the class has at least one virtual method). So what you can do is test the possibilities.  This is no fun, and almost always worse then using a clone() method, but there are rare situations where you have to do something like this.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a "factory like" class that creates Colors for you, you can implement a type erased upcasting copy constructor for the user. In your case, it probably doesn't apply, but when it does I find it more elegant than enforcing a clone function on implementers.

```cpp
struct IColor {
    /* ... */

    // One way of using this.
    // If you have a "manager" class, then this can be omitted and completely
    // hidden from IColor implementers.
    std::unique_ptr<IColor> clone() const final {
        return cpy_me(this); // upcasts
    }

    // There are other ways to riff around the idea, but the basics are the same.

private:
    friend struct ColorMaker;

    IColor() = default;

    using cpy_callback_t = std::unique_ptr<IColor> (*)(const IColor*);
    cpy_callback_t cpy_me = nullptr;
};

struct ColorMaker {
    template <class T>
    static std::unique_ptr<IColor> make_color() {
        static_assert(std::is_base_of_v<IColor, T>, "bleep bloop, no can do");

        std::unique_ptr<IColor> ret = std::make_unique<T>();

        // Encoding type T into the callback, type-erasing it.
        // IColor implementer only has to implement copy constructor as usual.
        ret.cpy_me = [](const IColor* from) -> std::unique_ptr<IColor> {
            return std::make_unique<T>(*static_cast<const T*>(from));
        };

        return ret;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Prototype design pattern to clone the object: https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/prototype. It is essentially declaring a `clone()` method in the interface and defining it in each of the implementations.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).